# Ground state energy for fermions with different spin orientation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, pauli-exclusion-principle, identical-particles, ground-state

Electrons are subject to a harmonic potential in one dimension, described by one-particle Hamiltonian $$H = \frac{P^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega X^2,$$ where $P$ are the momentum operator, $X$, is the position operator, $m$ is the mass of the particles, and $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the oscillator.

There is no explicit interaction among the particles and each particle is subject to the Hamiltonian. The allowed energies for each particle is
$$E (n) = \hbar \omega \left( n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

These particles have a total spin l $=1/2$ with two spin orientations $s = (+1/2,-1/2)$, thus fermions. How can I find out the ground state energy $E_0$ of the system? How can I approach the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spin-1/2 particles are fermions and thus constraint to follow the Pauli-exclusion principle. Thus you can fill each state with two particles. One with spin up and the other with spin down.

If you have $N=3$ number of particles then two-particle can be put in $n=0$ state and one  can put in $n=1$ so the ground state energy
$$E_g=2\times \hbar \omega \left( 0+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\hbar \omega \left( 1+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$